# Condition formatting between two dataframes , In second DataFrame i want remark true if condition valid with first DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting, conditional-statements

```
import pandas as pd
rows = [] #create rows
offset=50
for i in range(0,1000,offset):  
     rows.append([i, "   "])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["offset","Remark"]) # First data frame
```

---

```
First Data Frame
      offset Remark
0        0       
1       50       
2      100       
3      150       
4      200       
5      250       
6      300       
7      350       
8      400       
9      450       
10     500       
11     550       
12     600       
13     650       
14     700       
15     750       
16     800       
17     850       
18     900       
19     950  

#  second data frame imported from excel , which is as below

   Start  End
0     50  100
1    300  400
2    450  600
3    800  950
```

**Expected output require as below**- in offset column  "If value is in between or equal to Start & End  then remark column will be mark as True"

```
    offset       Remark
0        0       False  
1       50       True 
2      100       True 
3      150       False
4      200       False
5      250       False
6      300       True
7      350       True
8      400       True
9      450       True
10     500       True
11     550       True
12     600       True
13     650       False
14     700       False
15     750       False
16     800       True
17     850       True
18     900       True
19     950       True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html),

```
query = (
    " | ".join(f"{v['Start']} <= offset <= {v['End']}" 
               for _, v in df2[['Start', 'End']].iterrows())
)

# query: 50 <= offset <= 100 | 300 <= offset <= 400 | ...
```

---

```
index_ = df.query(query).index

df['Remark'] = False
df.loc[index_, 'Remark'] = True
```

---

```
    offset  Remark
0        0   False
1       50    True
2      100    True
3      150   False
4      200   False
5      250   False
6      300    True
...
```